# Resize a Windows 10 pinned tile / app by a script

Tags: powershell, vbscript, uwp, resize, tile

I've programmed an App / UWP with a live tile.

With a PowerShell script i can pin these App / UWP to the Windows 10 start menu.

How can i now resize these tile, for example to "wide", by a script like PowerShell / vbs / etc.?

Setting up a standard start menu layout will not work, because the user is already logged on.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? If yes, post the code.

Comment: So far i have not tried anything, because i have nothing found on google :-(
Resizing a pinned start menu tile by a PowerShell Script or other script language would be very nice :-)

Comment: Check out this cmdlet: `Export-StartLayout`. [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn283401.aspx) - it requires Windows 10 version 1511 or newer to use.

Comment: As I mentioned before: "_Setting up a standard start menu layout will not work, because the user is already logged on._" 
`Export-StartLayout` and `Import-StartLayout` will not work with Windows 10 Enterprise 1703 version 10.0.15063.483
The only one that i want, is to resize an pinned start menu app tile. For example from "Medium" to "Wide" by using powershell, visualbasic, or something else.